# What is the best way to select objects from the database by portions (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have the database with 1000+ objects. I want to make a button, by pressing which the first 20 objects from DB will be selected and loaded. If I press this button again, next 20 objects will be loaded and appended to previous objects. How to do this? Which SQL commands will help?

Comment: https://www.google.cz/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-mysql-limit-clause/amp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MYSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20;
...etc
```

Then you would just need a way to keep track of the offset variable.  You could use a session variable or a hidden variable on the page.  I'm sure there are other ways.